# JasperReports Server report audit report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I need to create a report to show last execution times for each report and who ran them.  Auditing report.  I've searched the database to see if I can get this information to be logged there but was unsuccessful.  Anyone try doing this? Is there already an audit reports that can do this with some tweaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auditing is built-in to the commercial editions of JasperReports Server. It would require a custom development effort to add it to the AGPL Community Edition of JasperReports Server.

EDIT: Given that you're using the commercial edition, then you need to turn auditing on in applicationContext-audit.xml. Search for this line:

```
<entry key="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.audit.domain.AuditEvent" value="false"/>
```

Refer to the Administrator's Guide for full details.

Comment: We are using a commercial version but it looks like i need to update applicationContext-audit.xml to set it up.  Is this the auditing you're referring to?  Does this write to the database or to a file?

Comment: where do you go to read these audit records. admin guide only shows import/export.

Comment: JasperReports-Server-Admin-Guide.pdf has 8 chapters. I guess you're looking at Chapter 6 "Import/Export". I'm looking at Chapter 8 "Auditing".